# jquery - look for 2 different elements after mouse up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

After a mouse up I want to track the closest table and perform a function if the mouse up was upon an element with a certain class. How can I combine these 2 actions within one mouse up?

JS

```
var currentTable;

$("body").on("mouseup",  function(e) { 

   currentTable = $(e.target).closest("table");
}


$("body").on("mouseup", ".searchIcon" function() { 

   $(".searchInputField").show();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the target for the class inside the first event handler, and you can drop the second handler

```
var currentTable;

$("body").on("mouseup",  function(e) { 
   if ( $(e.target).closest('.searchIcon').length ) {
      $(".searchInputField").show();
   }
   currentTable = $(e.target).closest("table");
});
```